# How to confirm if a popover is displayed on mouse over a element and how to get the inside text of the displayed popover using protractor

Tags: angular, protractor, popover, mousehover

**My protractor code**

```
var meover = element(by.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/span[1]/code'));

meover.getText().then(console.log);

browser.actions().mouseMove(meover).perform();

browser.sleep(2000);
```

How to get popover text?? see the images for better understanding

**Images**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
.........
.........
browser.actions().mouseMove(element(by.css('code.nocode.code-annotation'))).perform();
expect(element(by.css('.popover')).isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
popOver = element(by.css('.popover'));
popOver.getAttribute('title').then(console.log);
popOver.getAttribute('content').then(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do that with protractor ? You can just create a Directive [popover] or a component to do that
example :

.ts file :

```
import {Component, Input} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "popover",
    templateUrl: "popover.component.html"
})
export class PopoverComponent {
    @Input() title: string;
    @Input() content: string;
}
```

.html file :

```
 <ng-content></ng-content>
<div class="popover">
    <div class='header'>{{ title }}</div>
    <div class='content'>{{ content }}</div>
</div>
```

example of css :

```
popover {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.popover {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(50%) translateY(100%);
    width: 300px;
}

popover:hover > .popover {
    display: block;
}
```

I didn't tested it, but it should looks like my example.

To use it, you will write this on a HTML file :

```
Hint : place the mouse over <popover [title]="my title" [content]="text displayed on hover">me</popover> !
```

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: I need to test the mentioned scenario using Protractor.. i don't need create such scenario..

Answer (score 0):

```
var meover = element(by.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/span[1]/code'));
var toolbox = 'selector here';
browser.actions().mouseMove(meover).perform().then(() => {
    toolbox.getText().then((text) => {
        console.log(text);
    });
});
```

Comment: bro, how to get the text inside popover after hovering mouse on "me"? i need that code

Comment: what should be there in 'selector here'???i found no selection criteria... element by xpath returns "me" text.

Comment: `selector here` - put here selector for element from which you want to get text.

Comment: this is the web site.Please let me know what should it be?...you have the images to get help...please write me the code here. i am not getting any element which is for the popover.